# Is there specific name for simple XOR with ADD/SUB encoding?

Tags: xor, encoding

Several years ago a group of malware authors began using code like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
  ptr[j] = (ptr[j] ^ VALUEA) - VALUEB;
```

for encoding, and this to decode

```
for (j = 0; j < length; j++)
 ptr[j] = (ptr[j] + VALUEB) ^ VALUEA;
```

I've recently seen this pop up in seemingly legitimate software. This leads me to believe that there is a source for this type of encoding somewhere in the wild. I was wondering if there is a specific name for this type of encoding?

Comment: Both of these operations are addition. ^ is addition per bit, and + is addition per byte.

Comment: How about "really bad encryption"? Do VALUEB and VALUEA really never change?

Comment: I suspect that malware authors use this as a method to avoid signature-based virus checkers.  By cryptographical standards, this is a very weak method; however it may be sufficient to avoid simple-minded checks.

Comment: @mikeazo it is definitely "really bad encryption" but as poncho points out, it is a simple method for defeating basic sig-based detection approaches. the constants typically stay constant between versions of the malware and always stay constant within the binary.

Comment: *Obfuscation* might fit.

Comment: That could be characterized as a weak single-round [ARX (Addition Rotation Xor) cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_cryptanalysis) lacking Rotation.